# Can suggestion a solution for big, relational data analyzer please?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, rdbms, apache-spark-sql, opentsdb

I`m looking for some suggestions on my requirements. Below are the description of my requirements. Feel free to contact me for any details please. Even some suggestions on how I can describe my questions more clearly is also very appreciate:)

**Requirements description**

I have some data, the format is like below:

`router, interface,timestamp, src_ip, dst_ip, src_port, dst_port, protocol, bits
r1, 1, 1453016443, 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, 100, 200, tcp,  108
r2, 1, 1453016448, 10.0.0.3, 10.0.0.8, 200, 200, udp,  100`

As you can see, it is some network raw data. I omit some columns just to make it looks more clear. The volume of data is very big. And it is generating very fast, like 1 billion rows every 5min...

What I want is to do some real time analysis on these data. 
For example:

**draw a line using the timestamp**

> select sum(bits) , timestamp from raw_data group by router,interface where interface = 1, router=r1.

**find out which 3 src_ip sending the most data for one interface**

> select sum(bits) from raw_data where router=r1 and interface=2 group by src_ip order by sum(bits) desc limit 3

I have already tried some solutions and each of them is not very suitable for it. For example :

## rdbms

MySQL seems fine except a few problems:

> 1. the data is too big
> 2. I`m having a lot more columns than I described here. To improve my query speed, I have to some index on most of the columns. But i think create index on big table and the index containing too many columns is not very good, right?

## openTSDB

OpenTSDB is a good timeseries database. But also not suitable for my requirements.

> openTSDB is having problem to solve the TOP N problem. In my requirements "to get top 3 src_ip which sending most data", openTSDB can not resolve this.

## Spark

> I know that apache spark can be used like RDBMS. It having the feature called spark SQL. I did not try but I guess the performance should not satisfy the real time analysis/query requirement, right? After all, spark is more suitable for offline calculation, right?

## Elastic Search

> I really give a lot hope on ES when I know this project. But it is not suitable either. Because When you aggregating more than one column, you have to use the so called nested bucket aggregation in elasticsearch. And the result of this aggregation can not be sorted. You have to retrieve all the result and sort by your self. In my case, the result is too much. To sort the result will be very difficult

So.... I`m stuck here. Can anyone give some suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why ES would not be able to achieve your requirements. I think you misunderstood this part

> But it is not suitable either. Because When you aggregating more than one column, you have to use the so called nested bucket aggregation in elasticsearch. And the result of this aggregation can not be sorted.

Your first requirement **draw a line using the timestamp** could be easily achieved with a query/aggregation like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "interface": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "router": "r1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_minute": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": "1m"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_bits": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "bits"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As for your second requirement **find out which 3 src_ip sending the most data for one interface**, it can also easily be achieved with a query/aggregation like this one:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "interface": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "router": "r1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_src_ip": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "src_ip",
        "size": 3,
        "order": {
          "sum_bits": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_bits": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "bits"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

According to your comment, your second requirement above could change to find the top 3 combination of src_ip/dst_ip. This would be doable with a `terms` aggregation using a `script` instead of a term which would build the src/dest combination and provide the sum of bits for each couple, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "interface": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "router": "r1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_src_ip": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "[doc.src_ip.value, doc.dst_ip.value].join('-')",
        "size": 3,
        "order": {
          "sum_bits": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_bits": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "bits"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that in order to run this last query, you'll need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting). Also since you'll have billions of documents, scripting might not be the best solution, but it's worth giving it a try before diving further. One other possible solution would be to add a `combination` field (`src_ip-dst_ip`) at indexing time so that you can use it as a field in your terms aggregation without having to resort to scripting.

Comment: Hi Val. Very appreciate. Regarding the second question. I change it to find out the TOP 3 combination of SRC_IP and DST_IP. Then ES can not make it. Because the sort_based_on_deep_metric feature requires that each bucket is single value bucket  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_sorting_based_on_deep_metrics.html.    I dont know if I `m having some misunderstanding on this. But if you can prove ES can solve this problem, It will be very very very appreciate

Comment: That can also be achieved without nested aggregations, I'm showing one solution in my updated answer.

Comment: really , really thank you. I will give a try first. Will comeback and update once done. Thanks again

Comment: No prob, glad to help. Also see my last update to my answer.

Comment: Hi Val, I did a few try. Still not succeed. Can I have your email please? So I can send you my steps.   Once succeed, I will come back and update this thread with the ultimate answer.

Comment: Hi VAL. Sorry I did not find any contact from your profile.. only linkin but it is not showing me your email.   However I write all the steps in my blog. The blog is written in English so it should be fine. Can you help to have a look please?  The link http://www.cnblogs.com/kramer/p/5140046.html

Comment: Can you also include the mapping you're using?

Comment: Hi Val, by mapping, I think you mean the raw data in ES. So I updated the post and add the query result. http://www.cnblogs.com/kramer/p/5140046.html

Comment: I mean also the mapping type (= the definition of your data fields) you get with `curl -XGET localhost:9200/sflow/_mapping`

Comment: If you remove the filter on dates, the aggregations are working as expected. So your query has some issues: 1) "agg" should be "aggs" (+ add a comma before "aggs" and 2) remove the "filter" in the "must".

Comment: Hi Val. I updated the post again. Hit some error... Can you help to look again? I re-edited the post to make it more clear

Comment: In the script, change this `.join('-')` to `.join(\"-\")` instead. It will work and you'll get results.

Comment: Hi Val, It worked!!! Thanks a lot. But still I have one last question. Sorry if I have been annoying.  I read this link regarding term agg https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html. Though not very clear yet. Any the link said the result or term agg could be inaccurate. Because it is return the top for each shards.. So In my case , is this result accurate? Or the inaccurate only happen on count agg? I`m confused in this part..

Comment: Awesome!! In your case, I would proceed as I suggested in my answer, i.e. by adding another field which is the combination of src/dst IP, so that you don't have to use scripting in your aggregation, but instead you'd use that new field in a simple terms aggregation. As for inaccuracy, you can play with the `shard_size` parameter to alleviate the problem, shall it arise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101032/discussion-between-kramer-li-and-val).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Axibase Time Series Database](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/) which is non-relational but supports SQL queries in addition to rest-like API. Here's a Top-N query example:

```
SELECT entity, avg(value) FROM cpu_busy 
  WHERE time between now - 1 * hour and now 
  GROUP BY entity 
  ORDER BY avg(value) DESC 
  LIMIT 3
```

https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/sql/#grouping

ATSD Community Edition is free.

Disclosure: I work for Axibase

Comment: Hi Sergei Rodionov ，  Is there any limitation on function for community edition? Also Is there any article introduce why ATSD? since there are already some TSDB like influxdb, opentsdb, even elasticsearch ?

Comment: SQL queries are supported across all editions. The overview link is: https://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/. Administrative part is http://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/download-atsd/administration/. There is no shortage of time series databases these days. There are 3 that run on HDFS/HBase - OpenTSDB, ATSD, Kairos.

Comment: I checked the website of ASTD. Looks like an exciting products. But the full distribution is not free. I think my boss wont agree to pay for this. Anyway, still thank you for all the information